# One event on several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
function Any(){
  this.b1 = $("#but1")
  this.b2 = $('<div id="but2" />')
  this.func = function(){
     alert('hello')
  }
  this.b1.on('click',function(){
   this.func()
  })
  this.b2.on('click',function(){
   this.func()
  })


}
```

I want to do something like this:

`(this.b1, this.b2).on('click',this.close)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `add()`

```
this.b1.add(this.b2).on('click',this.close);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/THqub/)

Answer (score 1):

I would keep an array of selectors:

```
//code
    this.selectors = ["#but1", "#but2"];
    $(this.selectors.join(",")).on('click', this.close);
//code
```

Comment: `this.b2` isn't from a selector, it's a disconnected element that has been created.

Comment: @Barmar I understand. If it is a hardcoded `id`, why not to put it in an array?

Comment: Because you can't use a selector if the element isn't in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#but1,#but2").on("click",function(){
this.func();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the advanced syntax of [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you may attach a listener to
a defined and stable object/selector (this) to look for the even on
dynamic  SubComponents/selectors (#but1, #but2)
witch may or may not exists ... or show up later.

```
this.on('click','#but1,#but2',this.close);
```

Or in the more general case:

```
document.on('click','#but1,#but2', function(){ $('#my_dialog').close});
```